# XPath select node with mixture of default and non-default namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have some xml and I want to select the password node using xpath (using C#)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <s:Body>
        <Search xmlns='https://temp.org'>
            <context>
                <Password>MyS3cretP@ssword</Password>
                <UserID>MyUserId</UserID>
            </context>
        </Search>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The following code does not find the node and I don't know why. I think it's something to do with some of the xml having a defined namespace and some using the default.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(request);
var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/s:Envelope/s:Body/Search/context/Password", nsmgr);
```

Without changing the contents of the xml how can I select the Password node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not finding the node because the `Search` node and everything within it is in the `https://temp.org` namespace. You need to account for that in your namespace manager and XPath:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(request);
var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
nsMgr.AddNamespace("t", "https://temp.org");

var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/s:Envelope/s:Body/t:Search/t:context/t:Password", nsMgr);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. A colleague just the same thing and everything working as expected now.